# Search Button Disabled when integrating youtube search API for Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am trying to integrate a search form that does video searches using Javascript Youtube API, i am trying this on localhost and i have replaced the client id properly.

Howvere when the page loads i have the search button disabled.

Any help in this aspect would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The search button is working now, i placed the JavaScript code in the head section, however I am getting 

TypeError: gapi.client.youtube is undefined
 

var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({

Comment: Debugging this issue would be must easier if you shared part of the code causing the problem or created a demo.

Comment: Hello JSuar, Thanks for you reply, i am unable to paste the entire code due to lenght restriction here, also i am working on local host. however, i have intgerated the code provided here  [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript) for searching vidoe from youtube.


I have also properly replaced the client ID in the code, but iam not sure whats going wrong here